# callback function with addeventlistener

Tags: javascript, function, callback, addeventlistener

I'm putting my addeventlistener function inside other appendingEvents function, cause some of the variables got created here. But i want to make my appendingEvents function not messy.

```js
function appendingEvents() {
  for (let i = 0; i < eventFullInfo.title.length; i++) {
    let classes = document.querySelector(eventFullInfo.class[i]);

      document.querySelector(`.delete-${eventFullInfo.class[i].substring(1)}`).addEventListener("click", function () {
      
        classes.innerHTML = "";
        eventFullInfo.class.splice(i, 1);
        eventFullInfo.title.splice(i, 1);
        eventFullInfo.date.splice(i, 1);
        eventFullInfo.type.splice(i, 1);
        eventFullInfo.desc.splice(i, 1);
        eventFullInfo.etime.splice(i, 1);
        eventFullInfo.stime.splice(i, 1);      
    });
    
  }
}
```

So i'm trying to make a function outside the appendingEvents functions, and just call it with addeventlistener function.

```js
function appendingEvents() {
  for (let i = 0; i < eventFullInfo.title.length; i++) {
    let classes = document.querySelector(eventFullInfo.class[i]);
    
    document.querySelector(`.delete-${eventFullInfo.class[i].substring(1)}`).addEventListener("click", deleteEvent(classes, i);
  }
}


function deleteEvent(classes, i) {
        classes.innerHTML = "";
        eventFullInfo.class.splice(i, 1);
        eventFullInfo.title.splice(i, 1);
        eventFullInfo.date.splice(i, 1);
        eventFullInfo.type.splice(i, 1);
        eventFullInfo.desc.splice(i, 1);
        eventFullInfo.etime.splice(i, 1);
        eventFullInfo.stime.splice(i, 1);

}
```

How this is supposed to look like? Cause created function above doesn't work.

Comment: Your deleteEvent function should return a function. Ex. `function deleteEvent(classes, i) {  
return () => { /* code here */ } }` because you are calling the `deleteEvent` function. The function returns `undefined` so your event listener has a callback of `undefined`. You want a function so you should return one.

Answer (score 0):

`addEventListener` takes a function as its second argument. What you are doing is calling the `deleteEvent` function and putting the result of the function there instead.

You can create an anonymous function that gets triggered instead and call `deleteEvent` from within that. You can then pass whatever you want into it.

```js
function appendingEvents() {
  for (let i = 0; i < eventFullInfo.title.length; i++) {
    let classes = document.querySelector(eventFullInfo.class[i]);

    document.querySelector(`.delete-${eventFullInfo.class[i].substring(1)}`).addEventListener("click", () => {
      deleteEvent(classes, i)
    })
  }
}


function deleteEvent(classes, i) {
  classes.innerHTML = "";
  eventFullInfo.class.splice(i, 1);
  eventFullInfo.title.splice(i, 1);
  eventFullInfo.date.splice(i, 1);
  eventFullInfo.type.splice(i, 1);
  eventFullInfo.desc.splice(i, 1);
  eventFullInfo.etime.splice(i, 1);
  eventFullInfo.stime.splice(i, 1);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [event listener callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_event_listener_callback) has one argument that is passed: the event object. The easiest way to pass custom data is creating an anonymous function which invokes your function.

```
function appendingEvents() {
  for (let i = 0; i < eventFullInfo.title.length; i++) {
    let classes = document.querySelector(eventFullInfo.class[i]);
    
    document.querySelector(`.delete-${eventFullInfo.class[i].substring(1)}`).addEventListener("click", function(){ deleteEvent(classes, i) });
  }
}
```

An alternate solution is to use [.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

```
function appendingEvents() {
  for (let i = 0; i < eventFullInfo.title.length; i++) {
    let classes = document.querySelector(eventFullInfo.class[i]);
    
    document.querySelector(`.delete-${eventFullInfo.class[i].substring(1)}`).addEventListener("click", deleteEvent.bind(null, classes, i));
  }
}
```